# Performance comparison for SWITCH vs IIF?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

Background: migrating legendary Excel Reporting projects into MS Access for the very need of database structure.

Limitation: Development environment is within Excel and Access. Due to large chunks of data processing and keeping of moving n-Months data, it can't afford to loop via recordsets.

Issue: In current Excel reporting platform, there are multi number of sub tools are used separately to process data. As a result ithas the priviledge to process small chunks of data by going through each row. Conditional checks are performed using IF-ELSE.

In proposed MS Access structure, these IF-ELSE are converted into IIF. Given theis situation, would like to know opinions on performance comparison of IIF vs SWITCH. Any better solutions are most welcome.

PS:  after importing source, the db is auto closed to compact and repair as it "bloats". eventually db should be compatible for both ms 2003 and 2010 packages

Comment: Care enough to give comments for Downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I think that may be here is what you want:

[Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)

> The Iif function returns one of two values depending on whether the expression is true or not. The following expression uses the Iif
>   function to return a Boolean value of True if the value of LineTotal
>   exceeds 100. Otherwise it returns False.
>
> The Switch function is useful when you have three or more conditions
>   to test. The Switch function returns the value associated with the
>   first expression in a series that evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks GianlucaBobbie! Writing from mobile I didn't add the references. Your answer is suitable for question title, however I am also keen to hear other solutions that could improve the current design. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think that `Switch` is a VBA function (like `Nz`) while `Iif` is an SQL one. That has a lot of implications that you can explore [here, on Allen Browne's site](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html).
Those VBA function should specially be avoided in queries when working in a client-server architecture (SQL Server/Oracle or similar backend).

Comment: Very interesting addendum, I'm probably guilty of doing that in some queries. But are you sure it makes a difference? If a query on a linked ODBC table uses `IIf()`, does Access or the ODBC driver translate that into something that can be evaluated server-side?

Comment: @Andre  I am pretty sure `Iif` is correctly translated by ODBC, while Nz is not.  Quite easy to test if you have a SQL Server with at least one large table + 1 other table that can be linked to it. Using